# Swift 3: Image downloaded from Firebase and saved to local storage not showing in app

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-storage

I am trying out a firebase storage function and I am unable to show the downloaded image in imageview. Download is successful but nothing shows. If I use a Image from assets it does show. Why is this not working?

DownloadViewController:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage
import Firebase

@objc(DownloadViewController)
class DownloadViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var statusTextView: UITextView!
var storageRef: FIRStorageReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    let filePath = "file:\(documentsDirectory)/myimage.jpg"
    let storagePath = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "storagePath") as! String

    // [START downloadimage]
    storageRef.child(storagePath).write(toFile: URL.init(string: filePath)!,
                                        completion: { (url, error) in
                                            if let error = error {
                                                print("Error downloading:\(error)")
                                                self.statusTextView.text = "Download Failed"
                                                return
                                            }

                                            self.statusTextView.text = "Download Succeeded!"
                                            print("filepath: "+filePath)
                                            let image = UIImage.init(contentsOfFile: filePath)
                                            self.imageView.image = image
                                            self.imageView.layoutIfNeeded()
                                            self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true

    })
    // [END downloadimage]

}
}
```

Comment: Should you not download the image before writing it to a file? Seems to me you are confusing writing to Firebase Storage and downloading the content of an URL at the Firebase storage

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .resume at the end of your function block like so:

}).resume

Comment: For now it gives the same result. I found out however that the part: UIImage.init(contentsOfFile: filePath) = nil. Do you know why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the issue here is that your file doesn't exist:

```
let filePath = "file:\(documentsDirectory)/myimage.jpg"
```

Likely doesn't resolve to the correct user documents directory, and you should use something like (pardon the Obj-C, already answered this question with it):

```
NSURL *tmpDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()];
NSURL *fileURL = [[tmpDirURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"hello"] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"txt"];
```

This will also prevent issues of "works on the simulator but doesn't work on a device" and vice-versa.